# Update check after running reusable workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I have this workflow I'd like to alter, today I check in a YAML file, some code runs and unless i've manually done the prework will fail.  If I want it to do it for me I can comment `!confirm` otherwise I'm blocked.

```yaml
name: Check and Run
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
jobs:
  . . .
  do_checks_and_work_if_true:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/plan.yaml
    secrets: inherit
    with:
      . . .
```

I enter `!confirm`, the reusable workflow checks again if I've done that work and this time succeeds.

```yaml
name: Rerun On Confirm Comment
on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [created]
jobs:
  . . .
  if: github.event.issue.pull_request != '' && contains(github.event.comment.body, '!confirm')
  do_checks_and_work_if_true:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/plan.yaml
    secrets: inherit
    with:
      . . .
```

However - after this runs a second time, even though it's a considered a success in the Actions tab, it's still reporting failed/red from the original check.

Do I have to reference that original run somehow and update it via the API? I see there's docs on [GitHub checks](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/checks/runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-check-runs-for-a-git-reference) but I'm not positive if this is the right path or there's an easier way.

Comment: One way is to pause a workflow by using GitHub Environments and setting up required reviewers for the environment applied to the job, in the repository settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see there's docs on GitHub checks but I'm not positive if this is the right path or there's an easier way.

I do not see an "easier" or more native way to do that: you can indeed use the GitHub Checks API to update the status of the original run.
In the `Rerun On Confirm Comment` workflow, add a step that triggers a script to update the status of the original check run using the GitHub Checks API.

That script would:

- use the [GitHub Checks API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/checks/runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-check-runs-for-a-git-reference) to list all check runs for the pull request.
- identify the check run related to the `Check and Run` workflow.
- [update the status of that check run](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/checks/runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#update-a-check-run) to success.

You would use that script in:

```yaml
name: Rerun On Confirm Comment
on:
    issue_comment:
    types: [created]
jobs:
    check_and_update:
    if: github.event.issue.pull_request != '' && contains(github.event.comment.body, '!confirm')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
        - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        - name: Rerun Checks and Update Status
        uses: ./.github/workflows/plan.yaml
        secrets: inherit
        with:
            . . .
        - name: Update Original Check Status
        run: |
            # Add script/commands to update the status using GitHub Checks API
```

You will require a GitHub token with the necessary permissions (`checks:write` and `checks:read`). That token should be stored securely and used in the script for authentication.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Variables
GITHUB_TOKEN="<YOUR-TOKEN>"
REPO_OWNER="<REPO-OWNER>"
REPO_NAME="<REPO-NAME>"
CHECK_RUN_ID=<CHECK-RUN-ID>  # You should find a way to get this ID
HEAD_SHA="<COMMIT-SHA>"      # The SHA of the commit for which to update the check run

# GitHub API URL for updating a check run
API_URL="https://api.github.com/repos/${REPO_OWNER}/${REPO_NAME}/check-runs/${CHECK_RUN_ID}"

# Data for updating the check run
PAYLOAD=$(cat <<EOF
{
  "name": "mighty_readme",
  "head_sha": "${HEAD_SHA}",
  "status": "completed",
  "conclusion": "success",
  "completed_at": "$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")",
  "output": {
    "title": "Mighty Readme report",
    "summary": "The check run has completed successfully."
  }
}
EOF
)

# Update the check run
curl -L \
  -X PATCH \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${GITHUB_TOKEN}" \
  -d "$PAYLOAD" \
  "$API_URL"
```

Instead of listing and "guessing" the check run ID, you could also, at the end of your initial job (the one you want to track), add a step to create a file containing the workflow run ID and upload it as an artifact.
GitHub Actions exposes the workflow run ID as the `GITHUB_RUN_ID` [environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables).

```yaml
- name: Save Check Run ID
    run: echo $GITHUB_RUN_ID > run_id.txt

- name: Upload Run ID
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
    with:
    name: run-id
    path: run_id.txt
```

In the job that needs the `CHECK_RUN_ID`, download the artifact from the previous job. And extract the run ID from the file.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Variables
GITHUB_TOKEN="<YOUR-TOKEN>"
REPO_OWNER="<REPO-OWNER>"
REPO_NAME="<REPO-NAME>"
ARTIFACT_NAME="run-id" # Name of the artifact uploaded in the initial job
WORKFLOW_RUN_ID_FILE="run_id.txt"

# GitHub API URLs
ARTIFACTS_API_URL="https://api.github.com/repos/${REPO_OWNER}/${REPO_NAME}/actions/runs/${GITHUB_RUN_ID}/artifacts"
CHECK_RUNS_API_URL="https://api.github.com/repos/${REPO_OWNER}/${REPO_NAME}/commits/${HEAD_SHA}/check-runs"

# Download the artifact with the run ID
# Get the download URL for the artifact
ARTIFACT_DOWNLOAD_URL=$(curl -s \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${GITHUB_TOKEN}" \
  "${ARTIFACTS_API_URL}" | jq -r ".artifacts[] | select(.name==\"${ARTIFACT_NAME}\") | .archive_download_url")

# Download the artifact zip file
curl -L \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${GITHUB_TOKEN}" \
  -o "artifact.zip" \
  "${ARTIFACT_DOWNLOAD_URL}"

# Extract the workflow run ID from the artifact
unzip artifact.zip "${WORKFLOW_RUN_ID_FILE}"
WORKFLOW_RUN_ID=$(cat "${WORKFLOW_RUN_ID_FILE}")

# Retrieve the check run ID using the workflow run ID
CHECK_RUN_ID=$(curl -s \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${GITHUB_TOKEN}" \
  "${CHECK_RUNS_API_URL}" | jq -r ".check_runs[] | select(.id==${WORKFLOW_RUN_ID}) | .id")

# Output the check run ID
echo "Check Run ID: ${CHECK_RUN_ID}"
```